# CakePHP integration tests - Is there something else to test?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I have methods like this in my code.

```
    public function businessDepartments()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'conditions' => [
            'Tags.tag_type_id' => 'businessDepartment'
        ]
    ];
    parent::_index();

    $this->set('columns', [
        'tag_value' => ['title' => __d('cockpit', 'Business department')],
        'sort' => ['title' => __d('cockpit', 'Sorting')]
    ]);
    $this->_setURLsWhenAdd();
}
```

I can call this method with the class "Tags" and action "businessDepartment". 
This is how _setURLWhenAdd() looks like.

```
    /**
 * this method is setting the URLs inside the add
 * @return setter
 */
protected function _setURLsWhenAdd()
{
    // Set a new Url for the Add-Button in the index-View
    $this->set('dataAjaxUrl', "/tags/add/businessDepartment");

    // Sets the refreshable-Class on the element and the ajax-url where the element can get fresh data
    $this->set('refreshable', '/tags/businessDepartments');
}
```

I have a test which look like this.

```
public function testBusinessDepartments()
{
    $this->get('/tags/businessDepartments');
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Is this what I want to test ? Could/should I test something more ? Except entrance and response from this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this what I want to test ? Could/should I test something more ? Except entrance and response from this method ?

Test if the view vars are present?

I think they should be accessible through `$this->_controller->viewVars` in the tests. If not figure out how to get to the controller instance.

Another way to test if the page looks and does what you except it to do (JS wise) you can implement acceptance tests as well. See http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests There is a codeception plugin for Cake3 as well.

Also you should not use string urls `/tags/businessDepartments` but Router::url() and use the array syntax.

Comment: Hey Burzum, thanks for the nice ideas. I can't access viewVars. Could You give me an example how to access it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Can't access" is not an appropriate problem description. Check the API of the integration tests. There is in fact $this->_controller available for me (Cake3). Depending on the CakePHP version - you have not specified - accessing the view vars differs. Check the API docs or  the manual. :)